# How to exclude the INFO level logging from some package

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I need to exclude some package INFO level logging, while in console, it still output the INFO logging, how do I set the configuration, either from code or properties file?

Notice I used the configuration 
`log4j.logger.package_name=OFF`, it works well in most cases, but for one of package.

the whole log4j.properties is here:

```
# Set root logger level to WARN and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %p %c %x - %m%n

#it doesn't work for me
log4j.logger.com.agfa.hap.jboss.server.UnitTestBeanProvider=OFF

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

`log4j.logger.com.agfa.hap.jboss.server.UnitTestBeanProvider=OFF` turns the log output off only for the `UnitTestBeanProvider` class.

If you want to set the whole package's log level to OFF, you need to get rid of the specific class in the configuration:

```
log4j.logger.com.agfa.hap.jboss.server=OFF
```

Comment: Thx, I tried your suggestion, also false. let me clear that even in the UnitTestBeanProvider, the INFO logging is still in the console.